# papyrus diagram is not formatted well

Tags: eclipse-plugin, papyrus

I have existing project, where I have lots of class diagram, previously I have been using windows 7 on desktop, but now I have laptop and windows 10 installed on it.
when I open class diagram it is messed up[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I am using eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) and papyrus backbone 1.1.4.
I have tried to change my laptops resolution and many other things. but nothing seems to work.
refactoring all diagrams seems to be time consuming task, and other colleagues are still using windows 7.
is their any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer to my question:
My new laptop using High DPI setting. so adjusted all setting according to windows 7
you can do following things

1)go to regedit.
2)Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop
3)In right-side pane, look for a Win8DpiScalingand set the value to 1 and close Registry Editor.
5) in display setting change resolution to 1366x768
6)Restart your computer.